# Performing action in root view controller after dismissing modal view controller

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller

If I wanted to perform some sort of action right after dismissing a modal view controller, where exactly would I put the code? I know it wouldn't be in viewDidLoad because the rootviewcontroller was already loaded into memory (because it was just temporarily hidden by the modal view) and I'm not sure about viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear because of course the view has already been loaded into memory.

Comment: Why not put it immediately after the call to `dismissModalViewController:animated:`?

Comment: because what I'm trying to do is push another viewcontroller from the rootview and I can't do that from the modal class.  I tried putting the code right after dismissModalViewController and it just ignores it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ViewWillAppear will be called again in caller view controller when modal is dismissed, so with some logic can be a good place.

Otherwise you can think about implementing a delegate, or if synchronicity is not an option to be considered, you can send a custom NSNotification to be catched by the modal caller.

Comment: really? I didn't know viewWillAppear is called again after dismissing a modal. I will try this and tell you how it works out. thanks.

Comment: Worked Beautifully THANK YOU!!

Comment: Good ! Just a note however, if you are targetting an iPad application, I suppose viewWillAppear is not getting called, because the modal is not covering the whole screen, and viewWillDisappear is not called on the caller. In this case you have no other option than a delegate.